# all data of jqgrid in array with xmldata

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How to get all data of `jqgrid` in one array using "`xmldata`"? I know how to get data using "`local`" data,So I tried it with

```
var localGridData = $("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

but it not working for `xmldata`.

So can any one please suggest me, how to get all data in in array with `xmldata`.

Comment: What is "xmldata"? Do you mean `datatype: "xml"`? Do you use `loadonce: true`?

Comment: Yes exactly I am use datatype: "xml"! and no I am not used loadonce: true.Is that any problem to used or not used loadonce: true ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `datatype: "xml"` or `datatype: "json"` *without* option `loadonce: true` then internal parameter `data` will be not filled and you can't use `$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data')`. In the case you can use `getRowData` without additional parameters.

Comment: I tried with,                                                       var data = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData');
alert("data"+data); but it show [Object object].

Comment: @AloNE: You want get **all data** of jqgrid. The value returned by `$('#list').jqGrid('getRowData')` is **array** of items (objects). Every item represent the data of the row. You should read [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) of methods. The names of properties of items in array `$('#list').jqGrid('getRowData')` are the same as the values of `name` properties in `colModel`. If you have for example colModel:[{name:"myCol", ...}...] then `data[0].myCol` will be the value from `myCol` column of the first row.